# The only critical graphs of order four are $K_1\sqcup K_3$ and $K_{1,3}$

Tags: graph-theory

The graph $G=(V, E)$ is called a *critical graph* in terms of perfect matching if $G$ doesn't have a perfect matching, but for any edge $e \in E(H)$, where $H$ is the complement graph of $G$, $G + e$ has a perfect matching.

That means I will have to prove that any other graph of order four either has a perfect matching, or it doesn't have a perfect matching and for any edge $e$ I add $G + e$ doesn't have a perfect matching, right?

I want to use Tutte's theorem, but I don't see what differentiates $K_1 \sqcup K_3$ and $K_{1,3}$ from the other graphs of order four.

Comment: I think you've missed a possibility - You could have a graph $G$ that has neither a perfect matching nor is critical (i.e., there is some edge $e\in H$ such that neither $G$ nor $G+e$ has a perfect matching). For example, if $G$ consists of just $4$ isolated vertices, then $G$ is of this type.

Comment: By the way, I think using Tutte's theorem is probably too high-powered for such small graphs. Up to isomorphism, there are only $11$ simple graphs on $4$ vertices. Might be easier to simply check each manually.

Comment: Re first comment: Sorry, I misread the second paragraph. But the main point is still a minor correction: you need to show that any other $G$ either has a perfect matching, or it has none and *there exists* an edge e such that $G+e$ has no perfect matching.